# ViewPager fragment is sliding underneath the System bar

Tags: android-fragments, android-toolbar

I have a companion configuration app for my watchface, which just presents the various settings as fragments (one for each setting so you can swipe through them quickly)

I would like the fragment views to be scrollable while maintaining the action bar, but what's happening instead is that if you swipe up on the action bar it disappears under the system bar and is very hard to move back.

Sorry if that's unclear, but here are a couple of screen shots.
[image][image]

Here are my various layout and code components; let me know if there's more I need:

`AndroidManifest/xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" android:required="false"/>

<!-- Required to act as a custom watch face. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.permission.PROVIDE_BACKGROUND" />
<!-- So we can keep the screen on and start vibrations -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ref_watch_icon"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".RefWatch"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=
                        "com.pipperpublishing.RefWatch.wearable.watchface.CONFIG_DIGITAL" />
            <category android:name=
                          "com.google.android.wearable.watchface.category.COMPANION_CONFIGURATION" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

My activity's layout XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_previous"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_rew" />
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_ff" />
```

and most of my OnCreate:

```
     @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ref_watch);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
...
    /*-------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* Set up Settings Pager, Adapter, and floating action buttons */
    /*-------------------------------------------------------------*/
...
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the     menu setting sections
    mSettingsPagerAdapter = new  SettingsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
...
    mSettingsViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
...
    // Set up the ViewPager with the Settings adapter.
    mSettingsViewPager.setAdapter(mSettingsPagerAdapter);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This answered my question: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-App-ToolBar#using-toolbar-as-actionbar as well as some other stackoverflow questions. I added this code:

```
         Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
    params.setScrollFlags(0);  // clear all scroll flags
```

and voila, Action Bar no longer scrolls under the system bar.